# Why is the decimal part not being shown while calculating the average?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a, b, c;
    printf("Enter any three numbers:");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    float avg = (a + b + c)/ 3;
    printf("%.2f", avg);
    return 0;
    }
```

I could obtain only the integer part of the output with 0 in the decimal part

Comment: the result of (int)/(int) is (int)

Comment: You just need to have a float in your computing. Otherwise the result (from (int)/(int)) will be an int. For example just divising with `3.0f`should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dividing by `3`, which is an integer. You should cast one of the two operands to float, or divide by `3.0f`. Examples:

```c
(float) (a + b + c) / 3; // cast operator has the precedence over division operator
(a + b + c) / (float) 3;
(a + b + c) / 3.0f;
```

From the **Current C Programming Language Standard** – [ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf), you can read that *When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded*:

> **6.5.5 Multiplicative operators**
> **Syntax**
> **1** multiplicative-expression:
> cast-expression
> multiplicative-expression `*` cast-expression
> multiplicative-expression `/` cast-expression
> multiplicative-expression `%` cast-expression
>
> **Constraints**
> **2** Each of the operands shall have arithmetic type. The operands of the `%` operator shall have integer
> type.
>
> **Semantics**
> **3** The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.
> **4** The result of the binary `*` operator is the product of the operands.
> **5** The result of the `/` operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the second; the
> result of the `%` operator is the remainder. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is
> zero, the behavior is undefined.
> **6** When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional
> part discarded.109) If the quotient `a/b` is representable, the expression `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal `a`;
> otherwise, the behavior of both `a/b` and `a%b` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Integer arithmetic yields an integer result - `1/2 == 0`, `3/2 == 1`, `5/2 == 2`, etc.  Even though you're assigning the result to a float, there's no fractional portion to save.

To get the result you want, you'll want to change

```
float avg = (a + b + c)/ 3;
```

to

```
float avg = (a + b + c)/ 3.0f;
```